# Create SwatchLegend with some elements including opacity

Tags: list-manipulation, legending

```
colorList = 
 Flatten[{{Gray, Opacity[0.2]}, {Magenta, Opacity[0.2]}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][(# - 1)/5] & /@ Range[5]}]
```

This creates a list [image: {Grey]

But I want a list that joins opacity to the gray and magenta colors:
{{Gray,Opacity[0.2]},{Magenta,Opacity[0.2]},"Other colors"}

I tried catenate and partition to try and reform the list into the shape I wanted, but it did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The list that you want is the same used as a argument to Flatten?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can  construct your `colorlist` in a number of alternative ways:

```
colorList1 = {{Gray, Opacity[0.2]}, {Magenta, Opacity[0.2]}, 
   Sequence @@ (ColorData["Rainbow"][(# - 1)/5] & /@ Range[5])};

colorList2 = Join[{{Gray, Opacity[0.2]}, {Magenta, 
    Opacity[0.2]}}, (ColorData["Rainbow"][(# - 1)/5] & /@ Range[5])];

colorList3 = Flatten[{Opacity[0.2, Gray], Opacity[0.2, Magenta], 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(# - 1)/5] & /@ Range[5]}];

colorList4 = Flatten[{Directive[Opacity[0.2], Gray], Directive[Opacity[0.2], Magenta], 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(# - 1)/5] & /@ Range[5]}];



SwatchLegend[colorList1, Range[Length@colorList1]]
```

[image]

```
SwatchLegend[colorList2, Range[Length@colorList1]]
```

> same  picture

```
SwatchLegend[colorList3, Range[Length@colorList3]]
```

> same picture

```
SwatchLegend[colorList4, Range[Length@colorList4]]
```

> same picture